# Share on Linkedin using the SDK for iOS doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, share, linkedin-api

I'm using the mobile SDK for iOS (Version:1.0.7) to share something on `LinkedIn`. I can get the current account information, but when I try to share on `LinkedIn`,it always feedback the error description. This is my code:

```
let url:String = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares"
let payload:String = "{\"comment\":\"Check out developer.linkedin.com! http://linkd.in/1FC2PyG\",\"visibility\":{\"code\":\"anyone\"}}"
if LISDKSessionManager.hasValidSession(){
    LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().postRequest(url, stringBody: payload, success: { (response) -> Void in
          print("\(response.data)")
          }, error: { (apiError) -> Void in
          print("\(apiError.description)")
     })
```

Has anyone ever facing the same issue. Please help me,thanks a lot!

Comment: did you get any solution to solve this out...?

Answer (score 1):

This works in Swift:-

```
        if LISDKSessionManager.hasValidSession() {

        LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().postRequest(url, stringBody: payload, success: {
            response in
            //Do something with the response
            print("\(response.data)")

            }, error: {
                error in
                //Do something with the error
                print("\(error.description)")
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this doesn't work for me.I still get the error description:errorError Domain=LISDKErrorAPIDomain Code=403 "(null)",UserInfo={LISDKAuthErrorAPIResponse=<LISDKAPIResponse: 0x15eedad80>}.When run the samplApp,I also get the same error:errorCode:0,status:403.Do you have any idea

Comment: Check if you have already shared the content in LinkedIn. LinkedIn does not allow duplicate posts. Delete the post and check again

Comment: Hi, i need a help that how can i share data without LinkedIn Application ,because if there is no linkedin App install then It show the popup to install the app first.

Comment: hello i m facing same error 403 null , any idea about that error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I didn't set the correct permissions.

Make sure create session with share permissions.

```
let permissions = [LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION, LISDK_W_SHARE_PERMISSION]
LISDKSessionManager.createSession(withAuth: permissions, state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: ...
```